# KeyError with Pyro4

Tags: python, python-2.7, pickle, keyerror, pyro

Im trying to send an object with Pyro4. Seems Like it changes on the way, like Im using pickle.dumps and Pickle.loads on server it works but when I try to use pickle.loads on client it gives me a `KeyError.Server`:

```
def get_objects(self,player):
    "Notify player about new game state."
    data = self.player_serialize_gmf(player)
    tst = pickle.dumps("objects %s" % data)
    zzd = pickle.loads(tst)
    return tst
```

And client calling part :

```
   data = pickle.loads(self.game.get_objects(self.player))
```

And the error

```
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Pyro4-4.40-py2.7.egg/Pyro4/core.py", line 426, in _pyroInvoke
    raise data
KeyError: {u'state': (u'PYRONAME:player.server', (),
                     (u'setLast_ts', u'join', u'setName', u'getNextMove', 
                      u'getPoints', u'getName', u'setNextMove', u'isSpectator', 
                      u'getGj', u'setChar', u'getUuid', u'setPoints', u'setGj', 
                      u'getLast_ts', u'getChar'), (), 0.0, None, u'hello', 0),
                      u'__class__': u'Pyro4.core.Proxy'}
```

Comment: How come you are using pickle to serialize instead of the default, Serpent?

Comment: It still works with Serpent, if data is serializable. I just tried everything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in server side get_objects() method. I was using primitive and object types in same array. Appearantly they cant be in the same array.

I hope this will help.